# One of the factors greater than $x$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, factorization

Is there an easy way to tell Mathematica to find one of the prime factors of $n$ greater than $x$. For example, if $n=1299709\cdot 7919 \cdot 17$, is there a way to request a factor greater than $100$. Please note that I am not interested in finding all factors and filtering the result. My question is about stopping the algorithm as soon as a factor greater than $x$ is found.

Edit: If that capability is not built-in, is there a way to stop the factorization process as soon as one factor is found? There is no assumption about one of the factors being small.

---

> `FactorInteger` starts with trial division and then moves to Pollard
>   methods, ECM, and MPQS. In principle several of those can deliver a
>   nonprime factor. When the optional second argument is set, I'm not
>   sure if any factor is guaranteed to be prime. – [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau)
>   [Sep 30 '14 at 19:11](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61013/one-of-the-factors-greater-than-x#comment173571_61015)

Comment: `FactorInteger[n, k]` will stop after k different factors were found

Comment: Thanks. That definitely answers the edited question.

Comment: It actually answers the question entirely since one of the factors in `FactorInteger[n,2]` is greater than $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factoring algorithms work by finding *a* prime factor, then dividing by it, then continuing on the result, and so the prime factors are found in essentially random order, unless your algorithm is trial division (which I hope to God mathematica does not use). So, the answer to your question is: filtering is your only solution.

**EDIT** On the other hand, the OP's request for functionality to return a single prime factor seems quite reasonable (and present, as per @belisarius).

Comment: No, it doesn't do it by trial division. The algorithm used in FactorInteger is in fact quite advanced. I modified my question to something that is simpler.

Comment: I am going to accept this as answer just to close the question as answered. belisarius' reply is, of course, the real answer.

Comment: `FactorInteger` starts with trial division and then moves to Pollard methods, ECM, and MPQS. In principle several of those can deliver a nonprime factor. When the optional second argument is set, I'm not sure if any factor is guaranteed to be prime.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau That is the reason why I haven't posted the  comment as an answer